# How to access storage space in my google cloud instance VM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, storage

I have enabled all permissions, correctly uploaded software but while running my pipeline still get a following error:

```
Execution failed: generic::failed_precondition: pulling image: docker pull: running ["docker" "pull" "nfcore/s
arek:2.7.1"]: exit status 1 (standard error: "failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 1)
: write /opt/conda/envs/nf-core-sarek-2.7.1/src.zip: no space left on device\n")
```

Main thing is "no space left on device", although when checking the storage i have > 500 GB available. I'm logged in with main "owner" account, because i don't know how to log using cloud storage service account. So why am i unable to access this storage space?

Comment: Linux VMs have multiple mounted locations (directories). The one you are using is out of disk space. Use a command like **df -h** to view file system space. Your question does not show the command you are using, details on the file systems in your system, and the location where images are stored. For example, Docker typically uses **/var/lib/docker** to store data (OS specific). Try a command like **df -h /var/lib/docker** to see the space allocation for that mount point.

Comment: Hi @JohnHanley, i use working directory called gs://neon-mote-323609-life-sciences, am not sure how to test it's storage capacity..

Comment: Hi @juststuck please try to use the command [df -h](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/df1.html) to see the free capacity of this device, this can be [mounted](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-mount-and-unmount-file-systems-in-linux/#mounting-a-file-system) in a VM to verify the space.

Comment: Hi @NadiaEspinosa, so i have 400 GB of storage in my root, however, the actual working directory i use gs://neon-mote-323609-life-sciences appears to have only 32 MB of storage. 

Program i use (nextflow pipeline df-core/sarek) explicitly says i have to have "gs//:.." as a working dir, so how to add the storage space to this

Comment: Hi @juststuck you can refer to the next link to [increase the space of the disk](https://gridpane.com/kb/how-to-increase-the-disk-space-of-your-google-vm-instance-with-no-downtime/).

Comment: Your comments are confusing. Your mention that you are using **gs://neon...**. You mention pipeline. Show the commands that you are running and where they are running. Note, Docker does not use or know about Cloud Storage. You are either leaving out important details or you are using something like **gscfuse** and you reconfigured where Docker stores its data.